# django rest framework serializer save() “got key error message”

Tags: python, django, serialization, unicode

sorry for the repost but I made a lot of mistakes in my first question I think it's better if I just asked it again with more details and less mistakes in explaining it.

---

I'm trying to use the save method on my custom django rest framework serializer.
I have a .create() method in the serializer and my views.py looks like this (simplified):

```
def some_method():
    validated_data = {
        'id': some_integer_id,
        'created_at': "some text"}
    context_data = {
        'user': request.user.id}
    obj_serialized = MyCustomSerilizer(data=validated_data, context=context_data)
    if obj_serialized.is_valid():
        try:
            obj_serialized.save()
            print Response(obj_serialized.data)
            return Response(obj_serialized.data)
        except BaseException as e:
            raise APIException(detail=e.message)
    else:
        raise ValidationError(obj_serialized.errors)
```

this returns an exception:

> Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `created_at` on serializer `MyCustomSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.
>   Original exception text was: u'created_at'.

here is my serilizer:

```
class MyCustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   id = serializers.IntegerField()
   created_at = serializers.CharField()

   def create(self, validated_data):
       print validated_data['created_at']
       user = self.context.get('user')
       return {'id': validated_data['id']}
```

the first line of create method prints the value of created_at field correctly. the data I send with the dict is unicode and so the keys for the dict turn unicode too but I doubt that's the case since I can print the validated_data['created_at'].
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer. the problem was actually from the part:

```
            print Response(obj_serialized.data)
            return Response(obj_serialized.data)
```

for some reason I it was not being rendered before. how that affected my serializer is beyond me. however I solved the problem by deleting the print line and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Why you try return not exists field 'message'? may be need change it

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print validated_data['created_at']
        user = self.context.get('user')
        return {'id': validated_data['id'], 'created_at': validated_data['created_at']}
        #                                     ^^^^
```

Comment: thanks that was a bug too but it had nothing to do with this problem